# Avoiding complete layout draws

Tags: android, performance, animation, transitiondrawable

I have a layout that has a button at one of its corners. When a certain condition is met this button is supposed to have its background fade in and out.

I am using TransitionDrawable to achieve this effect. The problem is whenever the animation starts, the entire screen is redrawn at the animation intervals. I just want the runtime to redraw the Button so that CPU cycles are saved for other things.

How can I achieve this?